# How to use the user input as parameter to write a query to create a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I think it should a very simple question but I can't find any information online so I have to ask this question.
I need to run this code on PostgreSQL

I need to **write a query** to use user input as a parameter to create a table.

For example, we have a ratings table like this

```
  |userid | movieid  |  rating

1 |  1    | 122      |  5.0

2 |  1    | 185      |  4.5

3 |  1    | 199      |  3.3 

4 |  2    | 110      |  5.0

5 |  2    | 199      |  4.0 

6 |  2    | 231      |  4.0
```

So if I want to create a table to show all the ratings by user 2
I can use the query below.

```
CREATE TABLE query0 AS
SELECT  ratings.userid, ratings.movieid,ratings.rating
FROM  ratings
WHERE ratings.userid = '2'
```

My question is: How can I get a table by parameter, let the user to input userid to create a table

I try something like this but definitely not working

```
CREATE TABLE query0 AS
SELECT  ratings.userid, ratings.movieid,ratings.rating
FROM  ratings
WHERE ratings.userid = :userinput
```

I need to run the code on PostgreSQL

Comment: Is there a specific reason to create a table for specific user?

Comment: You can easily do this in a plpgsql function.

Comment: You have to specify what database client API you are using. This will be possible easily, but the exact way depends on the programming environment. Add an appropriate tag!

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with a PL/PGSQL function in PostgreSQL 9.5:

```
select * from ratings;
 userid | movieid | rating 
--------+---------+--------
      1 |     122 |    5.0
      1 |     185 |    4.5
      1 |     199 |    3.3
      2 |     110 |    5.0
      2 |     199 |    4.0
      2 |     231 |    4.0
(6 rows)

create function create_table(p_userid int) 
returns boolean
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
 execute format('CREATE TABLE query0 AS
                 SELECT  ratings.userid, ratings.movieid,ratings.rating
                 FROM  ratings
                 WHERE ratings.userid = %s', p_userid);
 return true;
end;
$$;
CREATE FUNCTION

select create_table(2);
 create_table 
--------------
 t
(1 row)

select * from query0;
 userid | movieid | rating 
--------+---------+--------
      2 |     110 |    5.0
      2 |     199 |    4.0
      2 |     231 |    4.0
(3 rows)
```

However if you need to create a lot of tables the table name cannot be hardcoded and should be either a parameter or built automatically.